# Prospective StartOfTime and EndOfTime in Mathematica

Tags: date-and-time

When working with conditions for numbers we have a notion of `\[Infinity]` representing larger than any other number and similarly `-\[Infinity]` representing smaller than any other number.

But when working with dates is there a similar notion of `BeginningOfTime`/`StartOfTime` representing larger than any other `DateObject[...]` or `TimeObject[...]` and `EndOfTime` representing smaller than any other `DateObject[...]` or `TimeObject[...]` in Wolfram language for working with time conditions?

Note it should work with all other builtin function like `Min`, `Max`, `DateDifference`, `Greater`, `Less` etc.

Comment: One way to get that behavior would be to work with Unix timestamps instead.

Comment: That's a cool idea, I'll bring it up next time I'm watching a SW livestream. Might be worth emailing the suggestion to support as well.